# Is there a way to analytically determine a list of possible functions given a set of properties, or must each option be evaluated individually?

Tags: functions, functional-equations

For example, if I needed a function that satisfied both the equations $\lim\limits_{x \to ∞}f'(x)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to ∞}{f(x)}=∞$, would it be possible to reverse engineer potential options, or would I have to repeatedly check functions against the two equations until I trialled-and-errored my way into various solutions?

Comment: Even specifying *all* derivatives in the $x \to \infty$ limit is not enough to determine $f(x)$ uniquely. In this case an obvious start is something like $f(x)\propto \ln(x)+g(x)$ where $g(x)\to 0$ as $x \to \infty$

Comment: Keeping track of some basic examples, like $\ln(x)$ in this case, is certainly a good idea.  Of course, there are no guarantees that your list will contain examples of everything one might ask for.